# Unable to individually programmatically check check boxes in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` in WinForms which is hosted on a control used to specify which columns to make visible in a `DataGridView`.  No matter what I do, I can't programmatically change the state of any of the inidividual check boxes in the list!  I've tried adding them when the form is shown:

```
checkedListBoxItems.Add
(
    "Column Header Text",
    true
)
```

I've tried setting them to checked after adding them:

```
checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(0, true);
```

After either of these `checkedListBox.CheckedItems.Count` and `checkedListBox.CheckedIndices.Count` are `0`.  I also found, when debugging, I could inspect the checked state via `checkedListBox.Items.InnerArray.entries[0].state` and this was also `0` - however, if I changed this to `1` it would actually check the checkbox in question.  So, I then tried to get at that field using reflection but got as far as getting the field using `.GetField("state", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField)` and got back `null` - thus meaning I couldn't use this at runtime!

I also tried DataBinding but found out it isn't two-way and thus is worthless for this task (I still have to call `SetItemChecked` which doesn't work!).

I have setup a simple side-project just for the purposes of calling `Add` with the checked state argument and `SetItemChecked` and for some reason they do work in that project!  Any idea what state this `CheckedListBox` control may be in that's causing it not to work in my main project?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

This works well here:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create sample data
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Option A", true);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Option B", false);
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Option C", false);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This button toggle the "Option B" entry value
    bool val = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.FindStringExact("Option B")); 
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, !val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps, requires a checkedListBox named checkedListBox1, a button named GetButton a button named CheckItButton and a checkedBox named checkedBox1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckedListBoxExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] 
                { "FirstName", "LastName", "Street", "City", "Country" });
        }

        private void GetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var results = checkedListBox1.CheckedStringList();
            if (results.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing selected");
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", results.ToArray()));
            }
        }

        private void CheckItButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkedListBox1.FindItemAndSetChecked("City", checkBox1.Checked);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Place in a class file
    /// </summary>
    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {

        public static List<string> CheckedStringList(this CheckedListBox sender) => 
            sender.Items.Cast<string>().Where((item, index) => 
                sender.GetItemChecked(index)).Select(item => item).ToList();

        public static void FindItemAndSetChecked(this CheckedListBox sender, string valueToLocate, bool checkedState = true)
        {

            var result = (from @this in sender.Items.Cast<string>().Select((item, index) => new
                {
                    Item = item,
                    Index = index
                })
                where @this.Item == valueToLocate
                select @this).FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                sender.SetItemChecked(result.Index, checkedState);
            }

        }
    }
}
```